# How to get path of a database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need to get a path of an `SQLite` database in order to open it for a query for the syntax:

```
rDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, 0);
```

where `mPath` will be the path to the database and `rDb` is the database file.

The code is for this query statement:

```
public ArrayList<String> getList(){ //List Query

    String FOOD_TYPE = "";
    String LOCATION = "";
    String TAKEREST = "";
    ArrayList<String> NameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_ROWID, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TELEPHONE, COLUMN_EMAIL, COLUMN_MENUURL, COLUMN_WEBSITE, COLUMN_MOBILE, COLUMN_CUISINE, COLUMN_LOCATION, COLUMN_TAKEREST};
    rDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, 0);
    Cursor list = rDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns,"food_type = ? AND location = ? AND Restaurant_or_takeaway = ?", new String[] {FOOD_TYPE, LOCATION, TAKEREST}, null, null, null);

    for(list.moveToFirst(); !list.isAfterLast(); list.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("in loop", "msg");
        NameList.add(list.getString(list.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)));
    }
    rDb.close();
    return NameList;
}
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: `any idea on how to solve this` - solve what?  What problem are you having?  You created the database, just open it from there.  I don't see your problem.

Comment: i don't know how to open it as i need the path.  How do i get the path?

Comment: Without knowing where the database is, how can anyone help you to determine the path?  Where did you create it?

Comment: i have the hardcoded path:  "/data/data/com.example.fmf/databases/"  but i have been told this path won't be true for all devices so i am looking for a general way

Comment: It would have saved a lot of time to have included that information in the question!  `context.getDatabasePath()`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of databases from the context with `[databaseList]( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)`

Comment: i can see the method i just don't know how to implement it

Comment: What do you mean by `I dont know how to implement`? What exactly do you miss? Please give context and a bit more about problem and your knowledge, so that we know where to start with the explanation